# Graph the describes the peaks of a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, curves, poisson-distribution

Probably not a very smart question - barely know any of the more interesting parts of probability theory - but I noticed that the peaks of Poisson curves form what looks like a kind of logarithmic curve. Can't find anything which talks about what curve models the points, but it feels like it should be pretty easy to answer. Someone help me out?
[Pic of the curve plotted vs 1/(e^2log(x)) Seems close?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S481y.png)

Comment: "the peaks of Poisson curves form what looks like a kind of logarithmic curve" No idea what this means. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The mode of a distribution is the place where the PMF has the highest value (most probable).

The mode of a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ ( i.e. PMF $\lambda^k e^{- \lambda}/k!$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$ if $\lambda$ is not an integer, and is $\lambda$ or $\lambda-1$ if it is an integer (these two have equal PMF).

Lets stick with $\lambda$ being an integer (and the results are similar for non-integer $\lambda$). In this case, the probability of the mode is $\frac{\lambda^\lambda e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda!}$, and you want to look at the plot of the probability of the mode versus $\lambda$. Stirling's approximation says that $n!$ is approximately $\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$ for large $n$, so we can approximate $\frac{\lambda^\lambda}{\lambda!}$ by something like $e^\lambda/\sqrt{2 \pi \lambda}$.

So, the probability of the mode is approximately $1/ \sqrt{ 2 \pi \lambda}$. You should try plotting $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi x}}$ instead.